# Automated user creation through Jira tickets

Tags: python, powershell, automation, jira, jira-rest-api

Wondering if this has been done before tried searching around and have yet to see it.

The workflow would be once someone inputs a new user account Jira ticket it will pull the information and sync to AD with all the details - **username, department, description, location.**

I believe this can be achieved through the REST API Jira has, but not positive. I also found that this might be able to do the trick in automation process (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.intenso.jira.plugins.ad-integration-manager/server/overview) but have yet to deploy it to my staging environment.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Haha jumped the gun and did not make it clear enough.. need a cup of coffee will edit..trying to create users through jira tickets

Answer (score 1):

Second answer in this thread looks like it answers your question:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Active-directory-user-creation-via-Jira-service-desk/qaq-p/579025

*"...in plugin Active Directory Attr Sync, there is post function "Create user in Active Directory/Ldap Server""*

Comment: I did see this, wondering if the post function needs to be called like running a task from a server with ldap that runs everyday to bring all the tickets with new users to be created on the domain..

Comment: would this work with Azure AD?